# PHP and MySQL give two different week number for the same date

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why PHP and MySQL give two different values of month number for some particular date:

```
echo date('W', strtotime('2014-04-16'));
```

this gives **16**

while this:

```
SELECT WEEK('2014-04-16')
```

gives **15**

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: What does... SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'default_week_format'; ... return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `SELECT WEEK('2014-04-16',3)` for returning a PHP compatible value. The `,3` indicates that this has weeks starting on **Mondays** and weeks numbered **1-53**.

Answer (score -1):

Play with MySQL WEEK() function parameters: see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week)

Answer (score -1):

For the same result you should use *mode* parameter in MYSQL function with value of *4*.

**PHP**
    string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )

**W** *ISO-8601 week number of year, weeks starting on Monday (added in PHP 4.1.0)*

**MYSQL**

```
WEEK(date[,mode])
```

For *mode* values with a meaning of “with 4 or more days this year,” weeks are numbered according to ISO 8601:1988:

Comment: This is incorrect. Mode 4 in mysql is: 4 Sunday 0-53 with 4 or more days this year. Use mode 3.